# file_get_contents() in php - need to pass static parameters and it's not working

Tags: php, asp.net, include, file-get-contents

I have a simple file I have created:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://occupancyadvantage.com/shortquiz.aspx?sid=234"); ?>
```

I can only get the file to render properly when I remove the parameters (well, when you say properly, I doubt you would consider that (http://occupancyadvantage.com/processfree.php -- the %@ page.... is showing up)  But I could care less about that.

I'm just trying to get a php file to load this aspx file with the ?sid=243 parameter on the end of it.

I don't have access to curl - I have a few weeks without the tech guy here and I'm not allowed to make that kind of an install w/o him... I do have access to the ini file  here is what it does have.  If something isn't on, I don't know what it is:  http://occupancyadvantage.com/phpinfo.php

I've been killing myself with this and I just can't seem to figure it out.  Besides punching babies I figured this place was the best option.

If you could please, try to spell out your responses the best you can, as being vague will probably just end up with me researching and asking more questions.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I have spent a few days on this -- I started off including -- but because it was an asp.net file I had to do the file_get_contents() -- I have been through adding the sid post data as a way so I don't have to have that in the url in ("....aspx".$_POST['sid'];  

I have been through an extreme amount of reading through the php manual site copy and pasting code and tailoring it to my situation.

I would like to think my first question on this site wouldn't garner a -1 on the question.

Comment: I've put it into an iframe and it worked for me just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This note from [PHP's documentation on file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) might help:

> If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you
> need to encode the URI with urlencode().

So that would be:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(urlencode("shortquiz.aspx?sid=234")); ?>
```

If that doesn't work, maybe use the full URL?  As in:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(urlencode("http://your-site-here/shortquiz.aspx?sid=234")); ?>
```

Comment: Definitely use a full URL. PHP will **NOT** do an http request unless it's a full absolute url. Without the standard `protocol://host/resource` format, it'll just be seen as a local file request.

Comment: I had checked out urlencode and applied it how the manual referred to it, I also set it up so it was just after the .aspx information  --

the file reads:
<code> <?php echo file_get_contents(urlencode("http://occupancyadvantage.com/shortquiz.aspx?sid=243")); ?> </code>

This was one of the last things I went through.

Comment: Did you get it working yet?  I think you'd need to add `http://` before your domain name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't file_get_contents with parameters if it's a local file. Just like you can't actually open the file with the parameters in a text file, it doesn't make sense to F_g_c.

You can, if the aspx is http-able, use f_g_c(http:/...).

Otherwise, you'll have to use wget (there are nastier ways to do it such as exec, but don't use them unless you don't need security at all).

Comment: obviously f_g_c is shorthand for file_get_contents().

Comment: I should have put that i tried that already, the url.  Just hangs there....  if you copy and paste the url you will see it works fine

http://occupancyadvantage.com/testfgc.php

file reads:

<code> <?php file_get_contents('http://http://occupancyadvantage.com/shortquiz.aspx?sid=243'); ?>
</code>

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open the file named `shortquiz.aspx?sid=234` in the current working directory.  I'm guessing there is no such file in the current working directory.

If you want to fetch the *url* that *ends with* shortquiz.aspx?sid=234, you can try this:

```
file_get_contents('http://example.org/shortquiz.aspx?sid=234');
```

Of course, replace "example.org" with the full host and path for this URL.

Comment: I should have put that i tried that already, the url.  Just hangs there....  if you copy and paste the url you will see it works fine

http://occupancyadvantage.com/testfgc.php

file reads:

<code> <?php file_get_contents('http://http://occupancyadvantage.com/shortquiz.aspx?sid=243'); ?>
</code>

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an iFrame to do this.  I don't know what I was thinking.  Thank you for all of your time.